# How to know that a data is among a select element option value?

Tags: jquery

There is a field having a value , say `<input type="hidden" id="x" value="4">` ,  and a `select` element :

```
<select id="produit" name="produit[]" multiple="multiple" size="10" required>
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<$data['user']['produits']['cnt']; $i++)
    {
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data['user']['produits'][$i]['code'] ?>"><?php echo $data['user']['produits'][$i]['lib']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

How to know that the field's value is among the select's options values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the input fields value and use it against select option value, like:

```
var xval = $("#x").val(); //hidden input field value
//get the select option whose value is xval
var selOptionLen = $('#produit option[value="'+ xval +'"]').length;
if( selOptionLen ) {
  //exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
  var inputVal = $('x').val();
  $('#produit option').each(function(){
     if($(this).val()==inputVal)
      alert('value is among select values');
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh yes ! I forgot the each tip ! Its more days I didnt use it lol

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` in jquery to get all selected option value  to check the hidden value is there or not using `inArray()`

```
var selectedData = $("#produit option").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

if ($.inArray($("#x").val(), selectedData) != -1) {

    alert("data is available")
}
```